# Problema al consumir servicio REST con AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest

Bueno mi problema es el siguiente: tengo una aplicación web con `AngularJS` con la cual obtengo datos de perros de una base de datos con un `Servicio REST` implementado con `Jersey`, y los quiero mostrar en una tabla. El problema es que cuando carga la página hace la petición a través del servicio a la base de datos y como tarda en traer los datos de la base de datos, primero renderiza el `HTML`, y como en ese momento la variable que recibe los datos de la base de datos (`listaMascotas`) no tiene nada, no muestra nada. Y bueno, esa es la cuestión, ¿qué estrategias para solucionar este problema se pueden utilizar? He estado investigando un poco pero no encuentro nada que me sirva para solucionar el problema. Soy nuevo en esto de `AngularJS`.

Acá esta la vista de la página y en donde pretendo que se vea la tabla, me falta aprender `Bootstrap` para ponerle el estilo:
[image: vistaPagina]

Les dejo mi `index.html`:
[image: index.html]

Este es el controlador encargado de la tabla (`ListController.js`):
[image: ListController.js]

Y este es el servicio que hice (`mascotas.js`), que a su vez lo usa el controlador `ListController`, y que se encarga de hacer las peticiones al back-end:
[image: mascotas.js]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema es que tu servicio es asíncrono así que no devuelve realmente el valor, sino que obtienes un objeto promise.

Necesitas corregir tus servicios pues estas olvidando el **"return"**.

```
var guardar = function(mascota){
    return $http.post("rest/services/save/"+mascota)
    .then(function(response){
        return response;
    });
};
```

Segundo, cuando consumas el servicio no debes asignar el objeto promise, sino obtener su valor esperando que termine.

```
//Estas asignando una promise, no el resultado.
$scope.listaMascotas = mascotas.listar();
```

Deberias tratar cambiando el codigo de la siguiente forma:

```
mascotas.listar().then(function(data){
   $scope.listaMascotas = data;
});
```

Adicionalmente, los scripts de la aplicación de angular están en la cabecera, te recomendaría que estuvieran al final del body como lo están **jquery y bootstrap**.

### ¿Qué es una promise?

Un objeto promise es usado para el procesamiento asincrono. **Una promise representa un valor qe puede estar disponible en este momento, o en el futuro, o nunca.**

Esto permite asociar manejadores a acciones asincronas(como consultar un servicio web) que eventualmente seran exitosas o fallaran. **Así, los métodos asíncronos que uno construye (como tu con tu factory "mascotas") no devuelven el valor final, sino una promise para el valor en algun punto en el futuro.**

[image: Promise]

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Pero ese `.then(function(data))` no es lo que hago en la función listar del servicio `mascotas`?? Perdón por la ignorancia, es que no termino de entender esto de las promesas que devuelve `$http`. @Jesus Angulo. EDIT: acabo de probar y me devuelve este error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`.

Comment: sorry, tu servicio necesita corregirse tambien. Estoy editando la respuesta.

Comment: Genial, ya entendí ahora. Tenía muchísimas dudas con esto de las promesas y los métodos del servicio `$http` de `AngularJS`. Muchas gracias @Jesus Angulo